# How do I reduce server load for a dormant WordPress site using W3 Total Cache?

Tags: performance, wordpress, cache

My current host who did all performance optimization for me has jacked up their price to $1,000/month, so I was forced to move to a new host. The new host charges only $150/month. They give you W3 Total Cache with recommended settings, but then they take their hands off. Now, I'm left with Total Cache and no knowledge of how to best configure it for my situation.

I have a WordPress site that gets one million page views a month. I don't add new content to the site. It's totally dormant. Comments are handled by Facebook Comments. In other words, all the functionality of the website can be handled simply by HTML/JS/CSS. No backend really needed!

So, how do I best configure W3 Total Cache for a situation like this?

Comment: http://support.maxcdn.com/pullzone/wordpress-w3-total-cache/ - google turned up this...

Comment: @NathanC As I said, my host already offers "recommended settings". I'm not looking for generic settings. I'm looking for settings that will hopefully significantly reduce server load, given that the website is completely dormant.

Comment: Toss the site on Cloudflare and let them do the caching? There's no surefire settings - this is why hosting companies charge so much money: constant tweaking is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tools.pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com)

This will tell you where your site is slowing down, then try to fix that using the plugin. Google also has https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ that will also give you some information as to how you can increase server speed.

Without actually seeing your site it will be impossible to know exactly what could be holding it back but it's generally images.